# Parsing FCPx XML file with SimpleXML

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I am messing around with the XML that Final Cut Pro X spits out when you do an export. I am using SimpleXML to do the parsing and am running into some problems. I have used the example that is on the php website - http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php but my XML is a bit more complicated - here is an example:

```
    <fcpxml>
    <project name="Rought Cut 2" uid="A9BCAB6E-6D54-4809-834D-F764A741A71B" eventID="909C357C-BB9B-41E3-87A2-FC6AE3E940A0" location="file://localhost/Volumes/VideoMain/Final%20Cut%20Projects/Storm%20Chasing%20test/Rought%20Cut%202/">
        <resources>
            <format id="r1" name="FFVideoFormat1080p5994" frameDuration="1001/60000s" width="1920" height="1080"/>
            <projectRef id="r2" name="Storm Chasing June 7" uid="909C357C-BB9B-41E3-87A2-FC6AE3E940A0"/>
            <media id="r3" name="Start teaser" uid="Wn75vMb1R2anXdP2aQX5+g" projectRef="r2">
                <sequence duration="393393/72000s" format="r4" tcStart="0s" tcFormat="NDF" audioLayout="stereo" renderFormat="FFRenderFormatProRes422Proxy">
                    <spine>
                        <clip offset="0s" name="HS700 - 00023" duration="445445/120000s" start="5630434810/60000s" format="r1" tcFormat="DF">
                            <video offset="5629760136/60000s" ref="r5" name="00023 - v1" duration="897897/60000s" start="5629760136/60000s">
                                <audio lane="-1" offset="4503808109/48000s" ref="r5" name="00023 - a1" duration="719039/48000s" start="4503808109/48000s" role="dialogue" outCh="L, R"/>
                            </video>
                            <title lane="1" offset="2252173924/24000s" ref="r6" name="Basic Title: Amateur Storm Chasing Mk2
" duration="360360/120000s" start="86486400/24000s">
                                <text>Amateur Storm Chasing Mk2
</text>
                            </title>
                            <keyword start="234573339/2500s" duration="897897/60000s" value="Hs700"/>
                            <metadata>
                                <md key="com.apple.proapps.studio.reel" value="TS700"/>
                                <md key="com.apple.proapps.studio.scene" value="89"/>
                            </metadata>
                        </clip>
                        <clip offset="267267/72000s" name="GH2 - 2012-06-07 20:27:30" duration="126126/72000s" start="45045/72000s" tcFormat="NDF">
                            <video offset="0s" ref="r7" name="2012-06-07 20:27:30 - v1" duration="1966965/72000s">
                                <audio lane="-1" offset="0s" ref="r7" name="2012-06-07 20:27:30 - a1" duration="1311310/48000s" role="dialogue" outCh="L, R"/>
                            </video>
```

The XML is not just simple 123 but  so was wondering how I'd parse it. This is what I was using but looking at my MAMP / php error logs I see that I'm getting lots of errors -  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 14: parser error : (NOte: this error is not related to the code I posted).

This is the code I've been playing around with:

```
<?php
include 'example.php';
$fcpxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
echo $fcpxml->project['name'];
?>
```

I'm sure it's something simple. E.g. I see that the XML file I am parsing is using double quotes and the example is using single quotes.Perhaps it does not like some special character in the file, FCPx XML looks pretty complicated and I'm shite at programming but I figure it would be fun to write a script that spits out my all my clip names, total length of then, Keywords and other stuff in a nice neatly formatted page or document.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your XML parsing library, so can't speak directly to the parser itself. *However*, looking at the XML you posted, I notice a strange coincidence: the error says line 14 and the 14th line in your XML starts from a line break *within* quotes:

```
<title lane="1" offset="2252173924/24000s" ref="r6" name="Basic Title: Amateur Storm Chasing Mk2
" duration="360360/120000s" start="86486400/24000s">
```

Your attribute `name` has the opening quote and `Basic Title: Amateur Storm Chasing Mk2` on the first line, but the *closing* quote is on the next line. Parsers in general *hate* line breaks inside quoted strings unless it's done in a very specific way. To be sure this isn't just from pasting to Stack Overflow, take a look in your original file containing the XML and see if it has a line break there (make the window wider, turn off line breaks in the display options, etc). If it does, bring the line back together and try again:

```
<title lane="1" offset="2252173924/24000s" ref="r6" name="Basic Title: Amateur Storm Chasing Mk2" duration="360360/120000s" start="86486400/24000s">
```

Good luck!